# Cómo puedo cargar en mi LISTVIEW, elementos que tengan la misma ID

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy intentando crear un ListView en el detalle de otro ListView y me gustaría que este solo mostrara los elementos que posean el mismo ID del elemento en el que me encuentro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que sea más fácil entenderlo, os he puesto una imagen en la que se ve el problema. Aunque ponga "profundidad del ensayo: " realmente lo que estoy llamando, para que se vea más claro lo que quiero, es el ID del Sondeo.

```
package com.vidamrr.sptsoftware;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vidamrr.sptsoftware.entidades.SPT;
import com.vidamrr.sptsoftware.entidades.Sondeo;
import com.vidamrr.sptsoftware.utilidades.utilidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetalleSondeoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView campoId, campoNombre, campoEmpresa, campoProfundidad;

ListView listViewSPTS;
ArrayList<String> listaInformacion;
ArrayList<SPT> listaSPTS;

ConexionSQLiteHelper conn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_sondeo);

    campoId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campoId);
    campoNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campoNombre);
    campoEmpresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campoEmpresa);
    campoProfundidad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campoProfundidad);

    Bundle objetoEnviado=getIntent().getExtras();
    Sondeo user=null;

    if(objetoEnviado!=null){
        user= (Sondeo) objetoEnviado.getSerializable("sondeo");
        campoId.setText(user.getId().toString());
        campoNombre.setText(user.getNombre().toString());
        campoEmpresa.setText(user.getEmpresa().toString());
        campoProfundidad.setText(user.getProfundidad().toString());

    }

    //ListView
    conn=new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),"bd_sondeos",null,1);

    listViewSPTS= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewSPT);

    consultarListaSPTS();

    ArrayAdapter adaptador=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaInformacion);
    listViewSPTS.setAdapter(adaptador);

    listViewSPTS.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            String informacion="id: "+listaSPTS.get(pos).getIdSondeo()+"\n";
            informacion+="Nombre: "+listaSPTS.get(pos).getProfundidadspt()+"\n";
            informacion+="Empresa: "+listaSPTS.get(pos).getEnergyratio()+"\n";
            informacion+="Profundidad: "+listaSPTS.get(pos).getBoreholediameter()+" metros"+"\n";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),informacion,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            SPT user=listaSPTS.get(pos);

            Intent intent=new Intent(DetalleSondeoActivity.this,DetalleSondeoActivity.class);

            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("spt",user);

            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

private void consultarListaSPTS() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();

    SPT spt=null;
    listaSPTS=new ArrayList<SPT>();
    //select * from usuarios
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+utilidades.TABLA_SPT,null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        spt=new SPT();
        spt.setIdSPT(cursor.getInt(0));
        spt.setProfundidadspt(cursor.getDouble(1));
        spt.setGolpes(cursor.getDouble(2));
        spt.setGolpescorr(cursor.getDouble(3));
        spt.setEnergyratio(cursor.getDouble(4));
        spt.setIdSondeo(cursor.getInt(9));

        listaSPTS.add(spt);
    }
    obtenerLista();
}

private void obtenerLista() {
    listaInformacion=new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i=0; i<listaSPTS.size();i++){
        listaInformacion.add("Profundidad del ensayo: "+listaSPTS.get(i).getIdSondeo()+" - "
                +"Golpes corregidos: "+listaSPTS.get(i).getGolpescorr());
    }

}



}
```

Os dejo el código del activity que he programado y para ver que debería incluir, que por más que le doy vueltas no se me ocurre nada.

**NOTA ACLARATORIA:**
*Yo tengo dos tipos de elementos: los sondeos y los ensayos spt. Cuando creo un SPT, lo asocio a un sondeo ya creado. Básicamente lo que quiero es que en el ListView de la vista detalle de cada Sondeo (que es el detalle de otro ListView) me aparezca un Listview con los SPT's asociados a ese sondeo. Sin embargo, el Listview me presenta todos los SPT's creados y no solo los asociados.*

Muchas gracias y un cordial saludo

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, intenta explicarlo algo mejor para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Jesús, yo tengo dos tipos de elementos: los sondeos y los ensayos spt. Cuando creo un SPT, lo asocio a un sondeo ya creado.  Básicamente lo que quiero es que en el ListView de la vista detalle de cada Sondeo (que es el detalle de otro ListView) me aparezca un Listview con los SPT's asociados a ese sondeo. Sin embargo, el Listview me presenta todos los SPT's creados y no solo los asociados.

Comment: Vale, entiendo que estara asociados por algun id, tendrias que filtrar los SPT's dependiendo del id del sondeo al que pertece ese listView, nose si me explico?
cada ListView es un sondeo, que tendra un id, y tendria que tener una relación con los SPT's. o otra forma de hacerlo, cuando creas las Entidades o pojos, inserta la lista de SPT's en cada sondeo y despues las muestras directamente.
Espero que con eso te valga,si con eso no te vale si pongo algo de codigo.
Un saludo

Comment: Hola Jesús, gracias por tu respuesta. Para poner un ejemplo más claro. Lo que yo tengo programado ahora mismo es como si yo tuviera una base de datos correspondiente a "personas" y he creado otra a la par que me permite crear "mascotas" y que puedo vincular a cada "persona/dueño". De esta manera puede haber un dueño que tenga varias mascotas. Cuando entro en la info del dueño lo que quiero es que me aparezca una ListView con las mascotas de ese dueño. El problema es que me aparecen todas las mascotas, no solo las del dueño que visito.

Comment: Creo que mi problema puede ser `private void obtenerLista() {
        listaInformacion=new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0; i<listaSPTS.size();i++){
            listaInformacion.add("Profundidad del ensayo: "+listaSPTS.get(i).getIdSondeo()+" - "
                    +"Golpes corregidos: "+listaSPTS.get(i).getGolpescorr());
        }

    }` Porque en esa parte del código lo que hago es llamar al tamaño de la lista de SPT´s y no a los SPT's que tienen el mismo ID de Sondeo asociado.

Comment: Gracias @jesuscabrera por el tiempo dedicado.

Comment: Creo que una posible solución sería decir que listaSPTS.get(i).getIdSondeo() tenga que ser igual a campoId.

Comment: Buenas @jesuscabrera he conseguido hacerlo. No sé si es una salvajada (si fuera así, dímelo). Respondo a mi propia pregunta por si hubiera gente que pudiera tener el mismo problema. Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Esacto asi estaria bien, como te dije en el primer comentario, tendria que tener un id asociado, una realacion entre personas y mascotas, para poder identificar a que persona pertenece cada mascota, 
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

finalmente conseguí solucionar mi problema. Para ello lo que hice fue editar el código de la siguiente manera, en vez de poner solo esto:

```
private void obtenerLista() {
listaInformacion=new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0; i<listaSPTS.size();i++){
    listaInformacion.add("Profundidad del ensayo: "+listaSPTS.get(i).getIdSondeo()+" 

- "
                +"Golpes corregidos: "+listaSPTS.get(i).getGolpescorr());
    }

}
```

Lo que hice fue programarlo así:

```
 private void obtenerLista() {
    listaInformacion=new ArrayList<String>();


    Bundle objetoEnviado=getIntent().getExtras();
    Sondeo user=null;

    if(objetoEnviado!=null) {
        user = (Sondeo) objetoEnviado.getSerializable("sondeo");
        Integer sptsespe = Integer.parseInt(user.getId().toString());

        for (int i=0; i<listaSPTS.size();i++){
            if (listaSPTS.get(i).getIdSondeo()== sptsespe) {
                listaInformacion.add("Profundidad del ensayo: " + 
listaSPTS.get(i).getIdSondeo() + " - "
                                + "Golpes corregidos: " + listaSPTS.get(i).getGolpescorr());
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

No sé si será una salvajada. El getId me marca lo siguiente:

> Method invocation 'getId' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
>   less... (Ctrl+F1)  This inspection analyzes method control and data
>   flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false,
>   expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and
>   situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.
>   Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or
>   @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used
>   during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report
>   NullPointerException (NPE) errors that might be produced. More complex
>   contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example:
>   @Contract("*, null -> null") — method returns null if its second
>   argument is null @Contract("*, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") —
>   method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null
>   otherwise @Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method
>   which throws an exception if true is passed to it  The inspection can
>   be configured to use custom @Nullable @NotNull annotations (by default
>   the ones from annotations.jar will be used)

Pero la aplicación aparentemente funciona.

Un cordial saludo y gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda.